How should software questions be tagged?
Given the preponderance of Stack Overflow, I expect this site to have a lot of questions about software. However, software is just one of many things one may want to reverse engineer. The inclusion of other fields in the scope is a critical argument for the very existence of the site — otherwise, the reverse-engineering tag on Stack Overflow would be sufficient.
 So far all 7 questions are about software, but that's not a statistically significant sample. 
Should all questions involving software be tagged software, on the basis that they are the questions generally interesting to programmers and other people whose fields of expertise is software? Or should there be only finer-grained tags?

I think software may be too wide a tag; SO's war against the homework tag is quite similar IMO. I could foresee more specific tags perhaps serving the same purpose though (e.g x86, mips, arm).

@MathewHall But most software RE techniques are architecture-agnostic (at least to some extent)! The homework tag is a completely different case: it doesn't convey any information about the topic of the question (and it's ambiguous, to boot).

In those cases would a more specific tag suffice (e.g. vine, daikon, hol)? For providing accessibility with broad categories, what other top-level tags might crop up? I can only think of "hardware" to complement a software tag.

@MathewHall [tag:chemistry], [tag:mechanical-engineering], [tag:business-methods], …

I'd rather ask for tagging by OS and architecture/CPU type. I expect we'll have a vast majority of questions about software so tagging all of them would be somewhat redundant IMO.

I agree with Igor. Most of the questions are software related so that tag is somewhat redundant. However, hardware is something that should probably be made necessary for non-software questions to distinguish them. 

Hardware might be a bit broad if you ask me. The following would fit that tag but are quite different: physical reverse engineering (at silicon level), software and hardware features (hw signature checkers, RAM scramblers etc) that are embedded device related or digital/analog components (like figuring out what the purpose of an unmarked chip is)

@justsome I do understand that, but the site's community has users who are mostly software related. So, hardware questions are (at the moment) very few. If more questions (>10) do come up, then sure we should create more specific tags.
